# questions about docker --link parameter

Tags: docker

As we know, in one host with docker daemon, containers connect to the `docker0` bridge, and so containers can access each other by default.

Then what's the use of `--link` option? Is it any different with the `direct access by ip` way?

What does it actually do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/):

> When you set up a link, you create a conduit between a source container and a recipient container. The recipient can then access select data about the source
>
> When two containers are linked, Docker will set some environment variables in the target container to enable programmatic discovery of information related to the source container.

And some more:

> In addition to the environment variables, Docker adds a host entry for the source container to the `/etc/hosts` file. Here's an entry for the web container:

So, basically `--link` creates a set of environment variables and adds some entries to the `/etc/hosts` file in order to ease communication. But, the containers are still directly accessed via IP.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a container using `--link` option, Docker exposes the linked container into the new one in two ways:

- It creates a entry in `/etc/hosts` with the IP of the linked container and the alias given when creating the link.
- It exposes some information as environmental variables about the linked container. As [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/) shows:

> Docker will then also define a set of environment variables for each port that is exposed by the source container. The pattern followed is:

```
<name>_PORT_<port>_<protocol> will contain a URL reference to the port. Where <name> is the alias name specified in the --link parameter (e.g. webdb), <port> is the port number being exposed, and <protocol> is either TCP or UDP. The format of the URL will be: <protocol>://<container_ip_address>:<port> (e.g. tcp://172.17.0.82:8080). This URL will then be split into the following 3 environment variables for convenience:
<name>_PORT_<port>_<protocol>_ADDR will contain just the IP address from the URL (e.g. WEBDB_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.82).
<name>_PORT_<port>_<protocol>_PORT will contain just the port number from the URL (e.g. WEBDB_PORT_8080_TCP_PORT=8080).
<name>_PORT_<port>_<protocol>_PROTO will contain just the protocol from the URL (e.g. WEBDB_PORT_8080_TCP_PROTO=tcp).
```

It is not differences if you access via IP, but using links let setting the container ignoring the ip that will be assigned by Docker Daemon. Check [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

If you start the docker using `--icc=false` option, the container can't communicate to each other by default. You must use `--link` to connect two containers.